# book to learn calculus by examples and real world applications

Tags: calculus, reference-request, applications

Don't know if it's the right question in this section I'll ask it anyway. When I study math I barely understand theorems, but after being given the examples I can understand the theory behind it.

The funny part is that I really excelled in Linear algebra because I managed to understand why do we use matrices but I didn't manage to go on with calculus: integrals, limits etc. As for probabilities after understanding also the use of it in real world applications I managed to like it and understand. What I really lack in is Calculus, why do we use limits, derivatives, logs etc.

---

My question is the following:

Do you know any book for advanced calculus and algebra which is more oriented towards applications rather than theory. Of course there will be theory but with much more examples that can help me understand it.

---

Thank you.

Comment: You might consider instead picking up a book on classical mechanics based on calculus. Calculus was developed to answer physics problems. It is remarkable that it happens to be useful in many other forms and types of problem.

Comment: There was a really neat illustrated group theory book, but I can't remember its name, and can't find it searching. It was available freely on line at one point, and may still be. Anyone else remember this book?

Answer (score 2):

For an intro calculus text that uses applications, you can check out Calculus: An Intuitive Approach by Morris Kline.