# Real-world applications of integration textbook/online course

Tags: calculus, integration, reference-request

I'm currently going through MIT's 18.01SC - single variable calculus, and oftentimes I find myself stuck with some real-world problem that requires creating and solving integrals. Naturally, I want to be more fluent with integration and it's use as an instrument to solving bigger problems, as opposed to just solving them.

So what I'm interested in is some kind of a book or an online collection of problems where integration emerges naturally and you have to think how and why to use it, instead of just solving given ones. This OCW course is good, but I think I need more hands-on experience with integration before I feel confident enough to move forward.

I know I could read a physics textbook (IIRC electromagnetism has integrals all over the place, albeit multidimensional ones), but this feels like a too indirect and less than optimal approach to my problem.

Sorry if this question is not specific enough, I did my best to explain it :)

Comment: Maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178950/book-to-learn-calculus-by-examples-and-real-world-applications?rq=1

Comment: @Moo This looks exactly like what I've been looking for, thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome. I have also seen that there are many applied sections like this as a chapter or two in Calculus books and those have lots of problems like you describe - so I'd certainly look for those and there are royalty free variants on the web.